# Drawing arrowtips at the end of each segment in a polygonal path

Tags: asymptote, draw

I need to draw polygonal paths, with an arrow tip placed at the end of each segment like in the figure below.

[image]

The above image was made with Inkscape (I had to literally create the triangles for the arrow tips at A and B and orient them appropriately).

Can I get such arrowheads automatically in Asymptote? From what I can gather from the manual, there are a large variety of arrowtip  shapes available but no option to place them at the ends of each segment of a polygonal path.

The code below for instance produces

```
unitsize(5cm);
settings.outformat = "png"; 

draw((0,0) -- (1,0.2) -- (0,1)--(2,2), arrow=Arrow);
```

[image]

where the arrow is only at the endpoint (2,2).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in way to do it, but here is a short function I wrote to do it.  It uses the built-in `length()` and `subpath()` functions.

```
unitsize(5cm);
settings.outformat = "png"; 

void segmentArrows(path p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length(p); ++i) {
        draw(subpath(p, i, i+1), arrow=Arrow);
    }
}

segmentArrows((0,0)--(1,0.2)--(0,1)--(2,2));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about subpath!